# System no longer bootable: promise_fasttrack_raid_member

Tags: linux, boot, debian, raid, rsync

After a simple reboot on my home desktop, I received the following message:

```
Non-System disk or disk error
replace and strike any key when ready
```

Plugging a Debian live usb, I could check the following info via Disks GUI:

```
Contents: Unknown (promise_fasttrack_raid_member)
```

Considering that I never tried raid in my desktop, I'm completely puzzled how could such raid issue appear in it.
Even so, I've tried to enable/disable the RAID mode in the BIOS but the issue persisted.

Not sure if correlated but, just before the aforementioned issue, I was browsing the web and `rsync` some folders.
Since `rsync` was taking too long, I've ctl+c and reboot. After that the issue started.

###### Questions

1. What does `promise_fasttrack_raid_member` mean? How could a raid issue appear in a non-raid system?
2. The SSD SMART overall assessment is "Disk is OK, 8 bad sectors". However, some SMART attributes seems weird:

   - Reallocated_Event_Count  55
   - Current_Pending_Sector    8
   - UDMA_CRC_Error_Count      8

   Considering that this SSD is reasonably new (≈6 months old) and wasn't used in heavy duty cycles (personal use only), should I be worried about its health?
3. Any idea how to fix that?

---

#### Additional Information

###### System Specifications

- Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
- Storage: SSD 500GB Goldenfir
- Product Name: HP Compaq dc5850 SFF PC

  ```
    user@debian:~$ sudo dmidecode --type baseboard
    # dmidecode 3.3
    Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
    SMBIOS 2.5 present.

    Handle 0x0003, DMI type 2, 8 bytes
    Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
        Product Name: 3029h
        Version: Not Specified
        [...]
  ```
- Mainboard Model: HP 3029h

  ```
    user@debian:~$ sudo dmidecode --type system
    # dmidecode 3.3
    Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
    SMBIOS 2.5 present.

    Handle 0x0002, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
    System Information
        Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
        Product Name: HP Compaq dc5850 SFF PC
        [...]
  ```

###### Debug

```
user@debian:~$ sudo blkid /dev/sda
/dev/sda: TYPE="promise_fasttrack_raid_member"

user@debian:~$ lsblk /dev/sda
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 

user@debian:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: SSD 500GB       
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

user@debian:~$ sudo parted /dev/sda print
Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA SSD 500GB (scsi)                                               
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

user@debian:~$ sudo smartctl --health /dev/sda
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.10.0-10-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

user@debian:~$ sudo smartctl /dev/sda -A
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.10.0-10-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       2927
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       454
160 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
161 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       89
163 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       498
164 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       368
165 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       160
166 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       15
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       76
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       100
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       608239772
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       77063
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       86738546
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       58
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       40
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       699294
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       55
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       8
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       8
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       89
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       288010
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       204821
```

Comment: Check the SMART data of the disk, or add it to your post. Have you played with fakeraid?

Comment: @harrymc > "Check the SMART data of the disk": I've could not find any issues. According to DISKS GUI: `Self-assessment: Threshold not exceeded  |  Overall assessment: Disk is OK, 8 bad sectors`. Even so, I've including such test in the OP.

Comment: @harrymc > "Have you played with fakeraid?". No, never heard of.

Comment: It would have been better to include the SMART attributes. The disk assessment might be OK, but hard errors are interesting, even if there aren't enough for the assessment to change.

Comment: @harrymc > "include the SMART attributes." Ok, just updated the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The following SMART attributes are worrying :

```
Reallocated_Event_Count  55
Current_Pending_Sector    8
UDMA_CRC_Error_Count      8
```

This means that you had 55 hex (85 decimal) bad sectors on the disk.
By itself this is not too bad, but you also have 8 cases in
[Current Pending Sector Count](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9133),
which is defined as:

> The raw value of this attribute indicates the total number of sectors waiting for remapping.

This means that the firmware has detected 8 bad sectors and is still
attempting to recover their data, without success. If it succeeds
in the future, the value will decrease, but if it fails then after
some time they will become hard errors.

Your disk seem to be failing. The error you experience probably means
that one of the bad sectors is located inside the disk's header,
so causes the disk to be wrongly identified as a RAID disk.

I recommend to salvage your data (if you don't have backups)
and replace the disk.

Note that the following large number is not to worry about,
as a large number here is a
[good indication](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9131):

```
Hardware_ECC_Recovered  699294
```

Comment: Just for the records: This is a reasonably new Chinese SSD (≈6 months old) not under heavy duty cycles (residential use only). Since its first usage, this `8 bad sectors` was already there (no more, no less). So far, I've never had any technical issue with it.

Comment: > "Your disk seem to be failing." If this is really the case, I'm gonna strongly consider going back to HDD. At least I've never experienced such kind of abrupt catastrophic data loss with them in residential environments.

Comment: It's indeed rare for an SSD to be lost in this way. You may try to salvage it by reformatting. Even if this succeeds, I wouldn't ever trust again a disk that did this to me, and would at least review regularly its SMART attributes and have good backups. If the disk is still under warranty and can be replaced or reimbursed, I would advice to do so to be safe.

Comment: > "If the disk is still under warranty and can be replaced or reimbursed" I'm gonna do some additional tests (ex: BIOS RAID, testdisk scan) before blaming the Chinese Goldenfir. So far such SSD was very helpful.

Comment: Just to be sure: Notice that both your links ([Current Pending Sector Count](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9133) and [Hardware ECC Recovered](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9131)) are: 1) from 2013 and 2010, 2) for Windows operating system, 3) for Hard Drives. I'm assuming you still consider them relevant for my case, ie: 1) 2023, 2) Debian, 3) SSD. Let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: SMART is a standard for both HDD and SSD, followed more or less by all the manufacturers. It relates to the disk firmware, so is not specific to any operating system, although each OS will have its own tools for querying the disk firmware. To summarize: Your disk has undergone a catastrophic failure, which might be recoverable by formatting (or not), and it's up to you to decide what to do with it in the future. I can only put the facts on the table.